# astyanax column slice query how to do inclusive and exclusive column slice

Tags: astyanax

I have a composite column that I can do inclusive and exclusive on both ends of a range like so

```
    AnnotatedCompositeSerializer serializer = info1.getCompositeSerializer();
    CompositeRangeBuilder range = serializer.buildRange();
    if(fromInclusive)
        range = range.greaterThanEquals(from);
    else
        range = range.greaterThan(from);
    if(toInclusive)
        range = range.lessThanEquals(to);
    else
        range = range.lessThan(to);
    return range;
```

GREAT so far, but when I have a normal column family with no composite names where the names are either Integer, Decimal, or String, how do I do the same thing.  Right now I just have

```
        ByteBufferRange range = new RangeBuilder().setStart(from).setEnd(to).setLimit(batchSize).build();
```

but there are no methods for inclusive/exclusive.

How to do this one?

**NOTE: Integer and Decimal CAN be two's complement so they could start with fffff and who knows how long the values are since they can be as big as someone wants.**

thanks,
Dean